# Missing category to be shown at bottom

Tags: r, dplyr

I want category of 'Missing' to be shown at bottom in result after groupby. There can be any character value in column x. See example below.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c('Ap','LA','MN', 'Missing','ZA'),
                 y = c('PA','NA','DN', 'Missing','ZD'),
                 z = 1:5,
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(x1 = sum(z))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soultion using `dplyr::arrange`:

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(x1 = sum(z)) %>%
  arrange(x == "Missing", x)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x          x1
  <chr>   <int>
1 Ap          1
2 LA          2
3 MN          3
4 ZA          5
5 Missing     4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the factor levels, keeping "missing" at the end.

```
librrary(dplyr)

levels <- c(setdiff(unique(df$x), 'Missing'), 'Missing')

df %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = levels)) %>%
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(x1 = sum(z))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  x          x1
#  <fct>   <int>
#1 Ap          1
#2 LA          2
#3 MN          3
#4 ZA          5
#5 Missing     4
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can it be modified for all the character variables in dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to include other columns as well?

Comment: For all character variables - levels <- c(setdiff(unique(df$x), 'Missing'), 'Missing')

df %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = levels)

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari I am not sure if I am missing something but this works for all the character variables already.